# MongoDB conditional search with parent document and nested docs in array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

Let's say I have a mongodb "schema" like this:

```
offers: Schema = {
      name: String,
      validityStart: Date,
      validityEnd: Date,
      customized: [
         {
            validityStart: Date,
            validityEnd: Date,
            user: String
         }
     ]
}
```

By words: here we have a collection of offers, valid between the dates specified by validityStart and validityEnd. Each offer has a subarray which define that a user can have this offer "customized", i.e. having a longer time to use.

I can query all the offers available with

`Offer.find({ $and: [{ validityStart: { $lte: today } }, { validityEnd: { $gte: today } }] })`

but If "**user**" is provided, I need to create a query that show me all offers and show the "customized" ones by filtering via the user field.

An example to show what I want to achieve is this: imagine having some offers for December

```
[
    {
      name: "Soccer Game 2020",
      validityStart: "2019-12-1",
      validityEnd: "2019-12-31"
    },
    {
      name: "Golf Equipment",
      validityStart: "2019-12-1",
      validityEnd: "2019-12-31"
    }
]
```

but I let the user FOO to be an early bird of 1 month for the soccer game, I'll have:

```
[
    {
      name: "Soccer Game 2020",
      validityStart: "2019-12-1",
      validityEnd: "2019-12-31",
      customized:[
        {
           validityStart: "2019-11-1",
           validityEnd: "2019-11-30",
           user: "FOO"
        }
      ]
    },
    ---
]
```

How to return for all the user the "parent" dates but for some user, specified by the customized array, their respective dates? Like:

```
[
    {
      name: "Soccer Game 2020",
      validityStart: "2019-11-1",
      validityEnd: "2019-11-30"
    },
    {
      name: "Golf Equipment",
      validityStart: "2019-12-1",
      validityEnd: "2019-12-31"
    }
]
```

I dunno how to create a query like this.

I'm available to change the schema, I'm in the early stage of developments so it's not a problem.

Comment: So if a user is provided you wish to return the dates from `customized` field for that particular offer and rest of the offers would have standard validity dates? Can you update the question with what would a result in above example for user "FOO" would look like for better visibility.

Comment: @ambianBeing exactly as you stated. I edited the question accordingly

Comment: Have posted an answer taking a bigger use case. Try it out ..see if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be little more verbose than I would've liked for a solution, but gets the job done.
Besides would only suggest to store the dates as **`date` objects** in the documents if they are currently strings.

**Query:**

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      userCustomOffer: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$customized",
          as: "elem",
          cond: {
            $eq: ["$$elem.user", "FOO"]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      name: 1,
      validityStart: {
        $cond: {
          if: {
            $or: [
              {
                $eq: ["$userCustomOffer", []]
              },
              {
                $eq: ["$userCustomOffer", null]
              }
            ]
          },
          then: "$validityStart",
          else: {
            $arrayElemAt: ["$userCustomOffer.validityStart", 0]
          }
        }
      },
      validityEnd: {
        $cond: {
          if: {
            $or: [
              {
                $eq: ["$userCustomOffer", []]
              },
              {
                $eq: ["$userCustomOffer", null]
              }
            ]
          },
          then: "$validityEnd",
          else: {
            $arrayElemAt: ["$userCustomOffer.validityEnd", 0]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

**Sample docs taken as use case:**

```
[
  {
    name: "Soccer Game 2020",
    validityStart: "2019-12-1",
    validityEnd: "2019-12-31",
    customized: [
      {
        validityStart: "2019-11-1",
        validityEnd: "2019-11-30",
        user: "FOO"
      },
      {
        validityStart: "2019-10-1",
        validityEnd: "2019-10-31",
        user: "BAZ"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "Golf Equipment",
    validityStart: "2019-12-1",
    validityEnd: "2019-12-31",
    customized: [
      {
        validityStart: "2019-11-1",
        validityEnd: "2019-11-30",
        user: "BAR"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "Hockey Kit",
    validityStart: "2019-01-1",
    validityEnd: "2019-02-28"
  }
]
```

**Query Results:**

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "name": "Soccer Game 2020",
    "validityEnd": "2019-11-30",
    "validityStart": "2019-11-1"
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000001"),
    "name": "Golf Equipment",
    "validityEnd": "2019-12-31",
    "validityStart": "2019-12-1"
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000002"),
    "name": "Hockey Kit",
    "validityEnd": "2019-02-28",
    "validityStart": "2019-01-1"
  }
]
```

Comment: this is perfect. Is so brilliant, I've tanned a little bit. Thanks!!!